# How can I create groups for external ssh tools

Tags: phpstorm

Currently the only group available in the drop down is "External Tools". How do I create new groups? So that I can group commands by my different projects?

[image]

How can I create more of the "external tools" level groups (what you see in the groups drop down) when you edit one of the tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create more of the "external tools" level groups (what you see in the groups drop down) when you edit one of the tools?

Just type your own text in that field -- it's editable drop-down box

[image]